# Next static html create wrong path for assets on nested pages

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js

I have two types of pages in my Nextjs app:

```
 - index.html 
 -- admin/user.html
 -- admin/dashoard.html
```

In next.config.js I have

```
assetPrefix: "./",
```

When I run `next build & next export` I get static htmls with urls to assets like

```
<link rel="preload" href="./_next/static/css/47a9f0c415417b6241a6.css" as="style"/><link>
```

When I open page index.html it works well (path in html is `out/_next/static/...`) , but when I open admin/user.html I get 404 error, since it tries to get assets from `out/admin/_next/static/...`

How can it be solved by Nextjs or maybe Nginx?

Comment: Try: `assetPrefix: "/",`

Comment: @RichardSmith it would make path from the core of filesystem, not what I want project i deep inside filestructure

Comment: If your application is hosted in a subpath, shouldn't you be setting `basePath` and `assetPrefix` to the subpath?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I handled it using nginx, in next.config `assetPrefix:''`